# Crystal Reports 2008: records selection with with drop down selection and dates

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am trying to select records with parameter `drop down` and `From` and `to date`.

I don't know what wrong below query and I am not getting any record. I know, there are record for condition.

```
    Submission.Submission Status} = "Submitted" 
    and {Submission.Status} = "Active" 
    and
    ( 
      if {?Type} = "Application Date" then
      {
           {Application.Edit Date} IN {?Date From} TO {?Date To} 
      }
      else
      if {?Type} = "Submission Date" then
      (
           {Submission.Edit Date} IN {?Date From} TO {?Date To}
      ) 
      else 
      if {?Type} = "Selection Date" then
      (
        {Committee_Member.Position Start Date} IN {?Date From} TO {?Date To}
      )
 )
)
```

I tried below query which works perfect, when I tried with dates did not work. Any clue?

```
Submission.Submission Status} = "Submitted" 
    and     
    ( 
      if {?Type} = "Application Date" then
      {
           {Submission.Status} = "Active" 

      }
      ....
      ....
      ....
   )
```

Comment: I hate dates.  Could be the column, or could be the parameter.  Your date parameters set to date type?  Your column is a date data type?

Comment: @ca_wan `Submission.Submission Status} = "Submitted" 
    and {Submission.Status} = "Active" 
    and  {Submission.Edit Date} IN {?Date From} TO {?Date To}` work fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the column data types are correct and there are no typos, there is nothing really wrong with your formula. The only thing I can suggest is to simplify the statement and then debug it line-by-line until you find the issue. Start with the simplest formula you can, run the report, and see if it works. If it does, add the next line and retest.

For example, run the report with a type of "Application Date" and see if this gives any records. If not, something is wrong with your first two lines. If you see records, then try it again by uncommenting out the line with the date selection.

```
{Submission.Submission Status} = "Submitted" 
and {Submission.Status} = "Active" 
and
    ( 
      select {?Type}
      case "Application Date" : true
      //case "Application Date" : {Application.Edit Date} IN {?Date From} TO {?Date To}
      //case "Submission Date" : {Submission.Edit Date} IN {?Date From} TO {?Date To}
      //case "Selection Date" : {Committee_Member.Position Start Date} IN {?Date From} TO {?Date To}
      default : false
    )
```

Did that work? If so, try this next:

```
{Submission.Submission Status} = "Submitted" 
and {Submission.Status} = "Active" 
and
    ( 
      select {?Type}
      case "Application Date" : {Application.Edit Date} IN {?Date From} TO {?Date To}
      //case "Submission Date" : {Submission.Edit Date} IN {?Date From} TO {?Date To}
      //case "Selection Date" : {Committee_Member.Position Start Date} IN {?Date From} TO {?Date To}
      default : false
    )
```

and so on until you find the culprit.